# SHA-256 and MD5 sums differ on Windows and on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10

I am using on Windows fciv and on Ubuntu terminal for making SHA-256 and MD5 checksums of an `.iso` file. Checksums on Windows and Ubuntu differ.

But I checked the same `.iso` on Windows again, and sums are same.

Any idea what could cause this ?

EDIT: i use command -sha256sum "name of iso", how else i should do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Almost certainly, the way you're doing it from the Unix shell is adding a trailing newline.

Comment: Adding trailing newline ? What is that ? How do i avoid it ?

Comment: Trailing newline? How would this happen if the input is taken from a file?